# How to manage auditing in streaming application in Kafka and spark-sql?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

In our project we are considering using Kakfa with spark streaming, for PoC I am using spark 2.4.1 version Kafka and Java8.

I have some questions:

- How to handle missing data into Kafka topics ingestion?
- How to maintain the auditing for the same? What is the big data industry practice in this?
- What should be the recovery mechanism to be followed? Any links or videos for the same?

Comment: I didn't? And you can't find out who has. Maybe because the question itself is rather broad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to handle missing data into Kafka topics ingestion?

I don't understand this. Does it mean missing data in Kafka topic or missing out data from Kafka topic to Spark streaming?

The first one can't be handled unless you're producer of the data and you can change according to the reason. The second one is possible if the data is still available in Kafka topic managed by retention period on Kafka cluster.

> How to maintain the auditing for the same?

There are couple of things you could do. You can ask Kafka to manage those offsets by committing those offsets. Or you could write the offsets to any other location like HBase and from there you can get the message offsets upto which you've successfully processed. With latest Structured Streaming, you do not need to manage such low level details, Spark will manage in the checkpoint directory.

> What should be the recovery mechanism to be followed?

It depends on which choice you're using. If you've the offset numbers in HBase, you can read from HBase and use KafkaUtils class to get messages from given offsets number using:

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
          ssc,
          LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
          ConsumerStrategies.Assign[String, String](fromOffsets.keys.toList, kafkaParams, fromOffsets)
        )
```

More details on
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html